# 100 led string to 2 X 50 led stings

Tags: led

I have bought a 100 led flashing led string which I want to use as 2 50 led strings for the holly balls I have made for either side of the front door. 
I have a few questions for you all in this.
Firstly I want to have the joint in the middle of the front door so I will make up a socket to plug a string for either side into. When I have cut the wires I will end up with 2 50 led strings which will receive too much power and burn out the leds so what if I add a resistor to each string and what size resistor would I need? The output voltage from the transformer is 31V and 0.12A.

Secondly as I have to make a termination at the end of the cut string could I put the resistor in there or would I need to locate the common and put it in there as it's a 3 wire string?

If I can use the termination of the cut string to add the resistor would I be better removing the last led from the original string and adding the resistor for that string in the same way?

Many thanks in advance as my head is starting to hurt working this out.

Andy

Comment: 31 volts across 50 LEDs aint gonna shine bright. No santa this xmas if you do that.

Comment: As Andy says, 31 volts across 100 (or even 50) LEDs won't light the LEDs.  You will have to analyze the string to determine how the LEDs are actually wired, and at what points in the string you can cut it without breaking an LED group.  If you cut the string in the right place, you should not need any extra components, and all the LEDs should still light.  If you cut the string at the wrong place, you may lose three feet (or so, depending on the actual circuit arrangement) of LEDs.

Comment: I know the output voltage is right as it's a bought string of lights that work! But if I half the string and put the two halves in parallel then it's going to blow the leds isn't it?

Comment: Who can answer? Not enough information and some information appears contradictory.

Comment: What information do you want?

Comment: Information that makes the question sensible. At the moment you have a 31V power supply and that won't come close to lighting 50 leds. How about a technical link to the LEDs for a start.

Comment: @Andy808, you need to tell us the colour of the LEDs (because voltage drop will depend on that) and the number of conductors at any point along the string. Red, yellow and green LEDs drop about 2 V each, white drops more so that's how we know it's not one string of 100 LEDs but more likely, say, ten parallel strings of ten LEDs in series. Is there a sequencer or do they all come on together?

Comment: Thanks transistor.
They are white LEDs running on three wires from the transformer/flasher unit. There doesn't seem to be any conductors along the string and when they are turned on they flash on alternate LEDs. They can either all be on or just half in the flash sequence.

Comment: There are three wires going to the first two LEDs then it goes up to 5 wires until it gets to the 25th LED where it drops back to 3 wires.

Answer (score 2):

We're expecting a wiring configuration something like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLBzjl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(Don't mind the numbers on the LEDs.)

Your comments on the original post don't quite add up.

- You can see on the schematic above that we have three wires to the first two LEDs and then five and then three again. This matches your description except that you say it returns to three wires after 25 LEDs. As this isn't the mid-point of the string it doesn't make sense unless the pattern repeats as shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0HXNu.png)</sup>

Here we have eight strings of 12 or 13 LEDs. Four strings are wired in parallel on each circuit. This makes a bit more sense as 31 V should be about enough to power 12 or 13 white LEDs.

Have another look at your lights and see if the wires to 3 to first two lights, then 5 for a while, then 3 for two lights, then 5 ...

If this is the case we should be able to cut wherever there are three wires. We need some more information from you.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use LED without losing it brightness,you probably wanna use current sources.You can use n number of LED's without losing it's brightness using a constant current source.For two circuits,use two constant current sources.This work fine unless you have sufficient current to supply for all LED's in series with it.For small level,we you can use lm317 as current source,but for larger level,I don't have idea on IC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7iL1D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: He doesn't 'wanna' use a current source - he wannas to use his 31 V PSU.

Comment: If so,your circuit with series and parallel LED's are work fine without blowing up.

Comment: Yes. Since his lights work already then his PSU has current limiting or else the voltage is low enough that the current level is safe. He just wants to know if he can split the string into two parallel branches.